# Do `sort` and `ls` return array? If not, why can we iterate without having to ${x[@]}

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have just noticed that I can write:

```
for i in $(sort $path); do
  echo $i
done
```

And it prints out perfectly fine. But when it comes to array:

```
arr=(i am array)

for i in $arr; do
  echo $i
done

# output (bash)
i

# outpus (zsh)
i
am
array
```

So I have to expand the array with:

```
for i in ${arr[@]}; do
  echo $i
done

#output (bash)
i
am
array
```

I suspect that `sort` and `ls` return just plain string with space and `for` statement just loops with space as a delimiter, am I wrong?. So should I use string with space to loop instead of an array?

I don't know technical term much, sorry for confusing question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In `bash`, `$arr` is same as `${arr[0]}`

Comment: You need to double quote your variables to prevent word splitting and other side effects.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: no, they don't "return" anything (except a single integer exit code), but they output a stream of bytes. That stream may or may not be parseable into the array you expect.

Comment: Be sure to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Comment: Also, you need better test data if you think `for i in $(sort $path); do` works "fine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

```
    for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
          The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of
          items. <...>
```

So when you write `for i in ${arr[@]}` or `for i in $(sort $path)`, the shell substitutes the `list` in place of the expansion, and `for` iterates over `items` in that list that are delimited by the first character of `IFS` which is an special variable that defaults to a whitespace.

Therefore, you are partially right: `for` does loop with a space as a delimiter, but neither `sort` nor `ls` return a space-delimited string. For that matter, run `ls | xxd` to see a binary dump of the output - the filenames from your directory are delimited by `0x0a` which is ASCII for newline.